# How to run .ova appliance on Debian Squeeze XEN host?

Tags: virtualization, xen, debian-squeeze

I have a virtual appliance in a .ova format, but I need to run it on a XEN host. Xen host is running Debian Squeeze.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ova2free](https://github.com/poelzi/ova2free). It's a small python script, that could convert ova images to some useful format.